# Safari extension <a> link tag not working

Tags: xcode, safari-extension

I'm trying to convert my chrome extension to safari. In my chrome extension popup, I've an `<a>` tag that links to my website under a certain condition. Even though, the mouse changes to click mode once hovered, as it detects an `<a>` tag, clicking on it doesn't result in any redirection. Is there a reason why a tag doesn't work in safari? Is there special permission I shall request for that I couldn't find?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a blank to the element:

```
<a href="example.com" target="_blank" ></a>
```

Comment: Is it possible to open the link in the popup itself?

Comment: Good question, I believe so.